# Insert csv into table using pyodbc, dynamic number of column

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I'm trying to import csv files into database using pyodbc

However, I have problem because structure of my csv file is not constant, sometime it contains 5 column sometimes more
I don't know how to deal with dynamic number of column in code like this

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='|',skipinitialspace=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for row in df.itertuples():
   cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ' +  table_name + column_list +'VALUES (?,?)',row.col1,row.col2)
```

So I've tried to write dynamic code to generate values that have to be inserted

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='|',skipinitialspace=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for row in df.itertuples():
   list_value = list(row[1:])
   list_value2 = str(list_value)[1:-1]
   cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ' +  table_name + column_list +'VALUES (' + list_value2 + ')')
```

But have problem with character ' for example

`test values1  test's value2`

It is imported as "test's" and when I try to create list I receive query like

```
Insert into test_table(col1,col2) values 'test values1',"test's value2"
```

which return error

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're inserted in the rows RBAR (Row By Agonising Row), why not parametrise the `INSERT`s? Then you *can't* have problems unescaped single quotes (`'`).

Comment: Not to mention, the syntax is `INSERT INTO <Object Name> {(<Column List>)} VALUES (<List of Values>) {, (<List of Values>), ...};`

Comment: Why not just use `df.to_sql()` ?

Comment: @Thom A If I don't know number of parameters, how I can use parametrised INSERT?

Comment: @Gord Thompson Ok I will try

Comment: If you don't know the number of columns then how are you ensuring that you are inserting into the correct columns?

Comment: @Thom A csv template file is generated from currently existing table with all columns name ,but want to my application to be scalable, so If will I add new column to table  I would like to application handle it

Comment: @GordThompson df.to_sql() work very well, but now i have another problem
I would like to insert all correct rows and receive information about error, like truncated value, is it possible to deal with that ?
Right now function insert all values to the moment when find corrupted rows

Comment: That is a separate question.